# Javascript splitting

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say i have this variable

```
var image = "image.jpg";
```

I'm trying to split the content of the variable image and insert _thumbs into it to get something like `image_thumbs.jpg`.

How do i go about this?
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
function addSuffix(filename, suffix)
{
    var pos = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    var left = filename.substring(0, pos);
    var right = filename.substring(pos);
    var result = left + suffix + right;
    return result;
}

var image = "image.jpg";
var imageWithSuffix = addSuffix(image, "_thumbs");
// imageWithSuffix === "image_thumbs.jpg"
```

Or, just for fun, a much less readable but shorter solution using a regex:

```
function addSuffix2(filename, suffix)
{
    return filename.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, suffix + "$&"); 
}
```

Comment: nice solution. lastIndexOf is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
var image = "image.jpg";
image = image.replace(".","_thumbs.");
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant and simple. Worked like a charm, thank you very much.

Comment: Won't work if there is dot in the filename (before the extension).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

Way 1

```
var image = "image.jpg";
var splitVar = image.split(".");
alert(splitVar[0]);
alert(splitVar[1]);
alert(splitVar[0]+"_thumbs."+splitVar[1]);
```

Way 2

```
alert(image.replace(".","_thumbs."))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LqpL3/1/

Comment: Won't work if there is dot in the filename (before the extension).

Answer (score 0):

If the file name can contain multiple dots, you need to take the last of it. You can use Regex to do it:

```
var image = "image.jpg";
image = image.replace(/\.(?!.*\.)/, "_thumbs.");
```